# ¿Por qué se siguen añadiendo datos?

Tags: python

Si viste mi otra pregunta sabrás que estoy haciendo un lenguaje de programación y estoy con las funciones, he logrado gracias a su ayuda que funcionen claro no en el entorno completo del lenguaje luego de mas o menos hora hora y media logre que funcionen. El problema fue cuando probé a declarar dos funciones, esto es lo que tengo hecho:

```py
Functions = {}

def Inicio(Code:str):
    Code = Code.split("\n")

    for Line in Code:
            

        if Line.startswith("//"):
            continue

        else:
            Parse(Line)

def Parse(Line:str):
    if Line.startswith("Func"):
        if Line.endswith(";"):

            tmp_search = Line.removesuffix(";")
            Fline = Line.split("Func")
            Name = Fline[1]
            Functions[Name] = []
            FuncData = ScanFunc(Codigo,str(tmp_search))
            FuncData.pop(0)
            for Data in FuncData:
                Functions[Name].append(Data)
        else: pass #Devolver Error

def ScanFunc(Code:str,FuncDeclare:str):
    FunctionActors = []

    if "\n" in Code:
        Code = Code.split("\n")
        for Line in Code:
        
            if Line.startswith(FuncDeclare):
                FCode = Code[Code.index(Line)::]

                for tmp in FCode:
                    if tmp.startswith("EndFunc;"):
                        continue
                    else: FunctionActors.append(tmp)

        return FunctionActors

Codigo = """Func Hola;
Prueba;
EndFunc;
Func Adios;
Prueba;
EndFunc;
"""
Inicio(Codigo)
print(Functions)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
{' Hola;': ['Prueba;', 'Func Adiós;', 'Prueba;', ''], ' Adiós;': ['Prueba;', '']}
```

Cuando debería devolver:

```
{' Hola;': ['Prueba;'], ' Adiós;': ['Prueba;']}
```

Como ven, cuando se declara la segunda función se declara bien pero también se añade toda la declaración a los datos de la primera.

Comment: pregunta, qué hace la función `ScanFunc`?? por qué le pasas `tmp_search`??

Comment: La función ```ScanFunc``` toma la frase específica de declaración de variable ejemplo Func Prueba; cuando se declara la función de guarda en tmp_search la frase Func Prueba; luego recorro todo el código en busca de esa frase y las líneas siguientes luego chequeo si la línea no es ```EndFunc;``` añado la línea a una lista que luego es retornada en escénica esa función solo es para conseguir el contenido de la función entre su declaración y la palabra EndFunc que finaliza la declaración

Comment: @Christian probaré tu respuesta más tarde ya que no estoy con la PC a mano para probar

Comment: Totalmente ineficiente no hay necesidad de volver a recorrer todo el código, y lo peor es que eso se hará las veces que se haya declarado una función y aun peor, el codig9 puede ser tan extenso que te tomsria minutos procesar una función que esta al final del todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu código superficialmente parece que el error puede ser causado por esta línea

```
if tmp.startswith("EndFunc;"):
    continue
```

Como hasta el momento no has respondido mi comentario me he limitado a arreglar el código para que sea mucho más sencillo de entender y mantener para futuras funcionalidades.

Comencé convirtiendo las líneas en iterables con ayuda de la función `iter()`, esto aparte de permitirnos recorrer las líneas podemos usar la función `next()` y a su podemos pasar este iterable a otras funciones para que continúen con la iteración, que por ahora no la he utilizado pero puede que después te sirva después.

Luego modifiqué la función `Parse` para simplemente se limite a entender o procesar cada línea de código, en caso de encontrar la declaración de una función entonces llama a la función `ScanFunc` pasándole el iterable para que así continúe desde donde la anterior función se quedó y procese el contenido de la función.

```py
Functions = {}

def Inicio(Code:str):
    Code = iter(Code.split("\n"))

    for Line in Code:
        Line = Line.strip() #limpiamos la linea de espacios en blanco
        if Line.startswith("//") or not Line:
            continue
        else:
            Parse(Line, Code)#pasamos la línea y el iterable

def Parse(line:str, iterable):
    if line.startswith("Func") and line[-1]==";": #si son funciones
        _, name_func = line.split("Func ")
        FuncData = ScanFunc(iterable) #procesamos la función pasándole el iterable
        Functions[name_func] = FuncData #creamos la función en el diccionario
    elif line.endswith(";"): 
        pass #ejecutamos código normal
    else: 
        raise SyntaxError(f"Error de sintaxis en la línea {line}") #Devolver Error

def ScanFunc(Code):
    code_func = []
    for line in Code: #iteramos
        line = line.strip() #limpiamos la linea
        if not line: continue
        elif line.startswith("EndFunc;"): break #terminamos la iteración
        code_func.append(line)
    return code_func #retornamos el código
```

Creo que el código es auto-explicativo, por eso solo explicaré un pequeño detalle, que es esta línea:

```py
_, name_func = line.split("Func ")
```

Esto lo que hace es separa la declaración de la función que tenga una sintaxis de tal forma `Func <nombre_funcion>;`, al hacer `.split("Func ")` (con un espacio al final) estamos indicando que debe de hacer la separación de acuerdo a esa palabra y esto lo hice por 2 motivos, el primero es para evitar volver a quitar espacios en blanco en el nombre de la función, ya que nos dejaría el nombre con un espacio adelante. Por ejemplo

```py
print("Func algoo;".split("Func"))
>>> ['', ' algoo;']
```

Como vemos nos regresa el nombre con un espacio adelante, esto se resuelve agregando un espacio en la cadena pasa a `split`, sin embargo esto también ocurrirá si se escribe una función de esta forma `Func       algo;`, por lo que es preferible usar `.strip()` para limpiar nuevamente el nombre, pero esto puede ser corregido con la sintaxis de tu lenguaje, pues debes de definir como es que se escriben las sentencias, si habrá indentanción en las funciones o ciclos, palabras reservadas, cantidad de espacios, etc. Pero todo esto es trabajo del Parser, que debe de encargase de parsear cada token encontrado.

El otro motivo por el cual utilizo `.split("Func ")` (con un espacio) es para evitar problemas con otras declaraciones de código. Imaginemos que una variable se crea de esta forma `<nombre_variable>_var = <valor>;`, entonces puede pasar que la variable tenga el nombre `Func_var = 10;` entonces con el `split("Func")` esto dará un procesamiento incorrecto, ya que cumple con la condición `line.startswith("Func") and line[-1]==";"` sin embargo no se trata de una función. Y esto mismo puede pasar en la declaración de una función, por ejemplo:

```py
Func Func_algo;
prueba;
EndFunc;
```

Esto dará error debido a que utilizamos una sintaxis de *unpacking* (desempaquetado)  `_, name_func = line.split("Func")` donde se espera una lista de 2 elementos, pero debido a utilizar `.split("Func")` (sin espacio) nos devolverá una lista de 3 elementos. Y esto también depende de tu Parser, que deberá catalogar cada token y verificar la sintaxis de cada expresión.

Bueno sin más que decir, pasamos a probar el código.

```py
Codigo = """Func Hola;
Prueba;
EndFunc;
Func Adios;
Prueba;
EndFunc;
"""
Inicio(Codigo)
print(Functions)
```

Dando como resultado:

```
{'Hola;': ['Prueba;'], 'Adios;': ['Prueba;']}
```

Si tienes alguna pregunta puedes hacérmela en los comentarios y con gusto te responderé :D.

Comment: Christian lo adapte a la clase padre del constructor y solo he cambiado cosas de la función Parse para que se adapte a lo ya hecho cuando llega la función ```ScanFunc``` el bucle for me divide la linea letra por letra

Comment: No puedo adivinar, mejor edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código completo

Comment: ok lo solucione la clase constructor tenia asignada la variable Código (que es lo que le pasamos) y referenciaba esa instancia de Código en vez de la que se itera (Básicamente estaba pasando la variable equivocada) por cierto tienes Discord?